# HTML5 Table Tab Focus, how to always iterate over the same row with the tab key?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

The following situation: there is a HTML table.

With the tab key, the user can now go over the individual fields of the row.
At the last field, however, it jumps to the next row.

**What I want:**
it should jump back to the beginning in the current row and iterate over the elements again.
no row should be changed automatically

**My HTML Table**

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>bla</tr>
<tr>blub</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
<td contenteditable='true'></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: then add this functionality, you can bind events to when a key is pressed. Where exactly do you have problems with that?

Comment: i don't quite understand what you mean. is there an event that is triggered when tab changes row? so i can reset the tab focus?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: ok, one moment i edit my question :)

Comment: There is an event when you press a key. `addEventListener('keydown', function` ... now all you have to do is attach this to the fields in the row and write the function. focus the first element in the row again for example.

Comment: Why do you need this functionality? Users can use shift-tab to go backwards if they choose. What you're describing goes against standard web conventions and will make your site confusing to use and inaccessible.

Comment: @DiscoInfiltrator no its not against any standards. i rebuild a old internal web app. And the customer would like to have this functionality.

Comment: @marc it is 100% against expected web conventions to change the behaviour of the tab key like this. The tab key traverses through focusable elements on a page via DOM order. There are situations where you need to modify focus, like with navigation menus or overlays. That said, context matters and if the users know how to use the site like this then that can be okay - which sounds like it could be your situation if your customer is also the end user. :)

Comment: @DiscoInfiltrator ok i got it. :)

now it works in any case.

should I leave the question online or should I withdraw it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
the last element now has a function `onfocusout=setnewfocus()` and this simply sets the focus back to the first element.